# Delete ’0’ of unlabelled section in header using scrlayer-scrpage

Tags: header-footer, scrlayer-scrpage

I use the package scrlayer-scrpage to create my headers and footers. The introduction is an unnumbered section and therefore has no header. If I add `\sectionmark{Introduction}`, then it says ‘0 Introduction’. How can I get rid of the number ‘0’?

Currently, I am using the following code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{scrartcl}

\ProvidesPackage{preamble}
        
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
        
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearpairofpagestyles
        
\chead{\headmark}
\automark[subsection]{section}
\cfoot{\pagemark}
        
...
        
\begin{document}
        
\tableofcontents
        
\section*{Introduction}
\label{section:introduction}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\nameref{section:introduction}}
\sectionmark{Introduction}
        
...
        
\section{Section 1}
\subsection{Subsection 1.1}
\subsection{Subsection 1.2}
        
\section{Section 2}
\subsection{Subsection 1.1}
\subsection{Subsection 1.2}
        
\end{document}
```

Comment: Use `\addsec` instead of `\section*`. Then you don't need bother about `\addcontentsline` and `\sectionmark`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to use `\addsec{Introduction}` instead of all those instructions.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
        
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{nameref}

\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearpairofpagestyles
        
\chead{\headmark}
\automark[subsection]{section}
\cfoot{\pagemark}
        
\begin{document}
        
\tableofcontents

\clearpage

\addsec{Introduction}

\clearpage
        
\section{Section 1}
\subsection{Subsection 1.1}
\subsection{Subsection 1.2}
        
\section{Section 2}
\subsection{Subsection 1.1}
\subsection{Subsection 1.2}
        
\end{document}
```

[image]

Remove `\ProvidesPackage{preamble}` that's useless (and I'd say also wrong).